# $(this).addClass for multiple onclick='myfunction()'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my code, buttons are creating dynamically

```
<button class="same_name" onclick='myfunction()'>button name</button>
<button class="same_name" onclick='myfunction()'>button name</button>
<button class="same_name" onclick='myfunction()'>button name</button>
<button class="same_name" onclick='myfunction()'>button name</button>
```

and I want to add class to button which I clicked

```
function myfunction()
{
  $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, and you're adding the buttons dynamically, strip out the inline JS, and use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to attach [one listener to a parent container](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to watch for events from your `same_name` buttons, and then add a class for that clicked button. (I'm using [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) in this example.)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.same_name', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="same_name">button 1</button>
<button class="same_name">button 2</button>
<button class="same_name">button 3</button>
<button class="same_name">button 4</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Andy's solution is the proper one.
If you wish to roll with your own solution, just pass the event to the function.

```js
function myfunction(event){
  let eTar = event.target
  $(eTar).addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="same_name" onclick='myfunction(event)'>button name</button>
<button class="same_name" onclick='myfunction(event)'>button name</button>
<button class="same_name" onclick='myfunction(event)'>button name</button>
<button class="same_name" onclick='myfunction(event)'>button name</button>
```

Comment: @AshikKH, just a small note. Both jQuery (in 2006), and modern JS [removed the need for inline JS](https://www.codeconquest.com/how-the-separation-of-concerns-makes-programming-magic/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the vanilla JS answer (jQuery isn't necessary at all, for almost nothing in 2022):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function ({target}) {
  if (target.matches('button.same_name')) target.classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<button class="same_name">button 1</button>
<button class="same_name">button 2</button>
<button class="same_name">button 3</button>
<button class="same_name">button 4</button>
```

Comment: Haha. Oh, God: _opinion alert!_. I agree with you on principle that we should be teaching younger devs the merits of VJS, but we also need to remember that millions of sites still have it included as legacy code, and that's probably what they're dealing with. jQuery completely changed how I viewed JS development, and it's impact on modern development shouldn't be overlooked. And while I wouldn't recommend it now necessarily, we could say the same thing about React in a few years time. And then I'd be out of a job. :)

Answer (score 0):

use [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$('.same_name').on('click', function () {
  $('.same_name').removeClass('active'); // if you wants to remove class from other buttons
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="same_name active">1</button>
<button class="same_name">2</button>
<button class="same_name">3</button>
<button class="same_name">4</button>
```